# Jquery find all except

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML:

```
<div id="123" class="test">
   <div class="testMessage">Foo</div>
   <div><div class="testDate">2010</div></div>
   <div id="127" class="test">
      <div class="testMessage">Bar</div>
      <div><div class="testDate">2011</div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I have following JS/jQuery code:

```
$(".test").find(".testDate").val("cool 2010");
```

How to change JS/jQuery to find "testDate" class element except in children "test" class block without using children?

P.S. I know only about class name and I don't know how many divs can be nested.

Comment: `123` is not a valid ID; IDs must not start with a digit.

Comment: Why? I know about variable names but it is attribute of the tag (string), isn't it?

Comment: Your sample HTML is invalid, `<div class="class="test">`

Comment: @Mirgorod: The specification says so: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name.

Comment: I think the spec requires this because some languages check for numbers at the start of variables as a sign that possibly an operator was omitted.  You can't (in most languages) define a variable named "3", and "3a" could be read (by humans) as "3 * a", a3 doesn't have the same ambiguity.

Comment: Since everything is wrapped in a div with class "test" it will not be simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Its probably the weirdest selector I've ever written:

```
$("div.test").not(':has(> .test)').siblings().find('.testDate').text('cool 2010');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/6cbdu/3/

Explanation:

```
$("div.test")             // finds both the test divs
  .not(':has(> .test)')   // finds the inner test div
  .siblings()             // get all other divs except the inner test div
```

Comment: But <div><div class="testDate">2010</div></div> (2 divs)

Comment: Oh, this is was I was searching! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this and also div elements do not have a value property, use `html()` method to set the inner html or `text()`

```
$("div.test :not(.test)").find(".testDate").html("cool 2010");
```

If you can modify your main div id to "_123", you can straight away use the id selector like this

```
$("#_123 > div.testDate").html("cool 2010");
```

Comment: @Mirgorod - Did you try with id?

Comment: $("#123").find(".testDate:first").text("cool 2010"); - this works!

Comment: You can just try `$("#123 > div.testDate:first").text("cool 2010");`

Answer (score 1):

I think the not() selector might help.  You can learn more about it here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you try to select $('.test'), it will grab all elements with a class='test'. You need to start at the outermost body tag:

`$('body').children('.test').children(':not(.test)').find('.testDate').text('cool 2010');`